# text animation not working with color of background

Tags: html, css

So i tried a animation for text that it showing from left to right text, when i tried to hide that text with same color that background have, it didn't work, or so,

CSS

```
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0%;
    font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
}

body{
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(0, 0, 0), grey, white);
    background-attachment: fixed;
}


.menu{
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    gap: initial;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.sectiontwo{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

}

.container{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    isolation: isolate;
}

.spanWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    animation: textAnimation 6s forwards;
    z-index: auto;
}

.titlename{
    margin-left: 0;
    color: silver;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: auto;
}

@keyframes textAnimation {
    to {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}
```

HTMl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>CV</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>    
        <section>
            <button class="menu">About Me</button>
            <button class="menu">Materials for HighSchool</button>
            <button class="menu">Materials for Martial Arts</button>
            <button class="menu">Materials for Video Games</button>
            <button class="menu">CV</button>
        </section>
        <section class="sectiontwo">
            <article class="container">
                <h1 class="titlename">
                    Artur De Sas Żubr
                </h1>
                <span class="spanWrapper"></span>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>    
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried give some classes other positons or give background-attachment: fixed;, z-index, i expect to block that hide text be same color as background but it didn't happen.

Comment: The above code( When created as a "snippet" ) does nothing - there is no content within the `.spanWrapper` SPAN element to see and the background is a linear gradient so you'll not be able to apply either single colour or same gradient in order to hide content. You could, within animation, use transparent as end colour?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, I have changed the text `width` into `0` initially, and then I animate the text width `100%` by using keyframes.

Here is the updated code,

HTML Code,

```
<div>
    <section>
        <button class="menu">About Me</button>
        <button class="menu">Materials for HighSchool</button>
        <button class="menu">Materials for Martial Arts</button>
        <button class="menu">Materials for Video Games</button>
        <button class="menu">CV</button>
    </section>
    <section class="sectiontwo">
        <article class="container">
            <h1 class="titlename">Artur De Sas Żubr</h1>
            <span class="spanWrapper"></span>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS Code,

```
.titlename {
    color: silver;
    font-size: 40px;
    max-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: reveal 3s forwards infinite;
    border-right: 4px solid silver;
}
@keyframes reveal {
    to {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```